# Get the physical core count

Tags: multithreading, codenameone

Is there an API to get the number of physical cores available?

When running a CPU intensive phase, it would be useful to know
how many active threads might actually improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exposed by us. Currently even high core count mobile devices don't necessarily expose all of them.

I would generally avoid this strategy though as Codename One already has 3 threads per platform by default:

1. The native OS thread
2. The Event Dispatch Thread
3. The Network Thread

If you add more than one calculation thread it might start sapping CPU time from one of those other threads which might not be your intention.

If you have something ridiculously intensive to do you can use a micro benchmark to test the number of ideal threads on the device itself. Then save that data for future use.

Comment: I suppose so.  The intensive app is running a game AI, which needs all the cycles it can get.   These tablets are wimps!  Even an ipad2 is only 4% of my desktop.  And it's really odd that my fastest "tablet" is a windows asus tablet running an android simulator.